# Magento admin CMS page not working throw exception

Tags: magento2

For some reason the admin CMS page is not working , return "Bookmark with id "0" does not exist.". I am able to access all other admin panel , its just the CMS link return error. I tried re-deploying static content, but no luck.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Bookmark with id "0" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to your Database table **"mg_ui_bookmark"** become inconsistent. Check for primary key validation for it or you can remove the entry with "0" Primary key **"bookmark_id"** in that table. After removing entry please check structure of table and if there is no index found please add indexes by repairing your table. Before doing that please take backup of your DB.